# c++ header wrapper declaration in cython char array[] convert

Tags: python, c++, header-files, cython

some part of C++ header files:

```cpp
virtual int SubscribeMarketData(char * ppInstrumentID[], int nCount, char* pExchageID) = 0;
```

some part of `*.pxd`files declaration:

```
int SubscribeMarketData(char *ppInstrumentID[], int nCount, char *pExchageID) except +
```

but I can't make sure some of the c++ `char * ppInstrumentID[]` code declaration in cython.
What's the right code declaration?
how about in the `*.pyx` files?

Answer (score 1):

```
cdef char[] *thing
```

It actually makes way more sense this way, but it's confusing to work between the two (especially as error messages use C's form!).

Comment: How about the Cython doc reference [link](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html), if `cdef char[:] *ting`. how about this `:` stand for, python list slice?

Comment: No, `[:]` giex a memoryview which is completely different. A Python list should just be `list thing`.